# idiomatic C++ for creating a std::vector from the last n elements of a std::map

Tags: c++, vector, dictionary, idioms

What is the C++ idiomatic way of creating a std::vector from the last n elements of a std::map?

I am not interested in preserving the order in the vector.

I can copy the elements, like this:

```
    std::map< double, MyType > m;
    size_t n = 3;
    std::vector< MyType > v;
    std::map< double, MyType >::iterator it = m.end();
    while ( n-- ) { // assuming m.size() >= n
        it--;
        v.push_back(it->second);
    }
```

But, is there any other way, more idiomatic, to do it?

Comment: `double` is a *very* bad key type for a map. The precision of floating point values makes it generally unusuable.

Comment: @Xeo Thank you for your comment. What do you mean with "unusable"?

Comment: Well, imagine you do `map[13.37] = blargh;`. You're not guaranteed to get the same thing back with `map[13.07 + 0.3]`, for example, or `double d = 13.37; map[d] ...`, since not every number can be exactly represented as a floating point value. Google should provide further information, "floating point inaccuracy".

Comment: @Xeo OK, that's fine. Fortunately I did not think to use that map in the problematic ways you show :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::copy` would be suitable if you wanted to copy the types unchanged. However, `std::map<T,U>::iterator_type::value_type` is not `U` (the type you want to copy), but `std::pair<T,U>` (in other words, dereferencing a map iterator yields a pair of the key and value types), so a raw copy won't work.

So we need to copy the elements, performing a transformation along the way. That's what `std::transform` is for.

For convenience, I'm going to assume that your compiler supports C++11 lambda expressions and the `auto` keyword. If not, it can be fairly trivially rewritten as a functor. But we're looking for something roughly like this:

```
std::transform(map_first, map_last, std::back_inserter(vec), [](std::pair<double,MyType> p) { return p.second; });
```

Now we just need to fill in the two first parameters:

```
auto map_first = std::next(map.end(), -n); 
auto map_last = map.end();
```

The only tricky part here is that map iterators are bidirectional, but not random-access, so we can't simply say `map.end() - n`. The `-` operator is not defined. Instead, we have to use `std::next` (which takes linear rather than constant time for bidirectional operators, but there's no way around that).

(Note, I haven't tried compiling this code, so it might require a small bit of tweaking)

Comment: It's a good start.  (I particularly like the use of lambda.)  But what happens if the map doesn't contain `n` elements?  You need a check for that as well.

Comment: `map::value_type` is `std::pair<const T, U>`, btw.

Comment: @JamesKanze: true. I tried to omit all the nonessential stuff, such as error checking, since that just muddles up the example code, and I prefer to keep it as short and simple as possible. But obviously, to actually *use* the code, you'd have to handle possible error conditions.

Comment: @jalf Hmm. Not sure I approve of the statement "the nonessential stuff, such as error checking".  More to the point, I'm not sure that it's a good idea to omit it, since so many programmers do forget it in actual code.  Best set a good example (or at least mention that it has been omitted).

Comment: Nonessential in answering the question that was being asked. Yes, it is essential in actually writing working code, but so are many other things which I conveniently omit. The OP asked how to create a vector from the last N elements of a map (which implies that the last N elements in the map actually exist), so that is the question I tried to answer. Anyway, I just go by what *I* personally prefer, and when I ask questions, I by far prefer answers that stick to the point, and don't try to bundle it up with a half-dozen things that I *didn't* need to know. :) YMMV

Comment: @jalf Thank you, no problem with the lack of error checking... And, by the way, a comment in the snippet of my questions says "assuming m.size() >= n".

Answer (score 4):

`std::transform` would be the most idiomatic way.  You need a functional
object:

```
template<typename PairType>
struct Second
{
    typename PairType::second_type operator()( PairType const& obj ) const
    {
        return obj.second;
    }
}
```

(If your doing much work with `std::map` or other things that use
`std::pair`, you'll have this in your toolbox.)

After that, it's a bit awkward because you only want the last n.  Since
iterators into a map are not random access iterators, and you can't add
or subtract arbitrary values, the simplest solution is to copy them all,
then remove the ones you don't want:

```
std::vector<MyType>
extractLastN( std::map<double, MyType> const& source, size_t n )
{
    std::vector<MyType> results;
    std::transform( source.begin(), source.end(),
                    std::back_inserter( results ),
                    Second<std::map<double, MyType>::value_type>() );
    if ( results.size() > n ) {
        results.erase( results.begin(), results.end() - n );
    }
    return results;
}
```

This isn't the most efficient, but depending on `n` and where it is
used, it may be sufficient.  If you do want to avoid the extra copying,
etc. (probably worthwhile only if `n` is typically much smaller than the
size of the map), you'll have to do something fancier:

```
std::vector<MyType>
extractLastN( std::map<double, MyType> const& source, ptrdiff_t n )
{
    std::map<double, MyType>::const_iterator start
            = source.size() <= n
                ? source.begin()
                : std::prev( source.end(), n );
    std::vector<MyType> results;
    std::transform( start, source.end(),
                    std::back_inserter( results ),
                    Second<std::map<double, MyType>::value_type>() );
    return results;
}
```

(If you don't have access to C++11, `std::prev` is simply:

```
template<typename IteratorType>
IteratorType
prev( IteratorType start, ptrdiff_t n )
{
    std::advance( start, -n );
    return start;
}
```

Again, if you're doing much with the standard library, you probably
already have it in your toolkit.)

Comment: I always forget about `std::transform`.

Comment: @James Kanze Thank you, I appreciate the error checking. I know it is quite subjective (without any stated requirements) but why don't you just throw an exception in your extractLastN if the size of the map is < n?

Comment: @uvts_cvs Because it doesn't correspond to what I've usually needed: in most contexts where I've needed something like this, the `n` was to be understood as a maximum, but less would be acceptable.  If this is not the case, then of course some other handling would be necessary (maybe an `assert`, maybe an exception).

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple Boost.Range version:

```
#include <boost/range/iterator_range_core.hpp>
#include <boost/range/adaptor/map.hpp>
//#include <boost/range/adaptor/reversed.hpp> // comment in for 'reversed'
#include <map>
#include <vector>

struct X{};

int main(){
  std::map<int, X> m;
  unsigned n = 0;
  auto vec(boost::copy_range<std::vector<X>>(
    boost::make_iterator_range(m, m.size()-n, 0)
    | boost::adaptors::map_values
    //| boost::adaptors::reversed // comment in to copy in reverse order
  ));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing it is using a simple `for_each`:

```
    map<int,double> m;
    vector<double> v;
    //Fill map
    auto siter = m.end();
    advance(siter, -3);
    for_each(siter, m.end(), [&](pair<int,double> p) { v.push_back(p.second); });
```

**EDIT** Even simpler way is using `std::prev` with `for_each`:

```
    map<int,double> m;
    vector<double> v;
    //Fill map
    for_each(prev(m.end(), 3), m.end(), 
                  [&](pair<int,double> p) { v.push_back(p.second); });
```

Also, if you want fill the vector in reverse order you can use:

```
for_each(m.rbegin(), next(m.rbegin(), 3), 
        [&](pair<int,double> p) { v.push_back(p.second); });
```

Comment: But `std::copy` and `std::transform` are there for a reason... :)

Comment: @jalf: I'm pretty sure that reason isn't to force you to write dozens of lines of code to turn everything possible into a `transform`, though.

Comment: Where do you get "dozens of lines of code" from? Why would an answer using `transform` be longer at all?

Answer (score 0):

Do it backwards:

```
assert(n <= m.size());
std::copy(m.rbegin(), m.rbegin()+n, std::back_inserter(v));
```

bidirectional iterators FTW.

---

OK, I obviously wasn't awake yet, and that was wishful thinking. I still prefer walking backwards to get the last n though, so a working version looks like this:

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

// I'm assuming it's ok to copy min(m.size(), n)
template <typename Iter>
Iter safe_advance(Iter begin, Iter const &end, int distance)
{
    while(distance-- > 0 && begin != end)
        ++begin;
    return begin;
}

void copy_last_n(map<double,int> const &m,
                 vector<int> &v, int n)
{
    transform(m.rbegin(), safe_advance(m.rbegin(), m.rend(), n),
              back_inserter(v),
              [](map<double,int>::value_type const &val)
              {
                return val.second;
              }
             );
}
```

James Kanze already wrote the `Second` functor - use that if you don't have access to lambdas.

Comment: but in the vector, OP wants only value part of the map.

Comment: Good point! I may have to leave that as an exercise for the reader for now, and come back to it in a bit ...

Comment: There's also no `+` operator on map iterators. In other words, this just doesn't work. :)

Comment: And there is undefined behavior if the map contains less than `n` elements.

Comment: I asserted the size, but yes, it turns out to fail completely. Will fix later, unless a better approach has been accepted by then.

Comment: @JamesKanze: the answer to the question is also undefined in the map contains less than `n` elements. (the question is how to copy the last n elements. if they aren't there, then the question is just as meaningless as this answer, so I don't see the problem there)

Answer (score 0):

First, what do we want to write to be idiomatic? I suggest:

```
std::vector<Mytype> v;
v.reserve(n);
std::transform(
  limited(n, m.rbegin()), 
  limited_end(m.rend()),
  std::back_inserter(v),
  values_from(m)
);
```

Now we just have to make that code valid.

We can replace `values_from(m)` with a lambda (which doesn't need `m`), or implement it using James Kanze's class `Second` (in which case `m` is there for type deduction):

```
template <typename Map>
Second<Map::value_type> values_from(const Map &) {
    return Second<Map::value_type>();
}
```

Implementing `limited` is a bit of a pain. It's a template function that returns an iterator. The iterator type it returns is a template that wraps another iterator type, and forwards everything on to it except that it keeps track of `n`, and acts like an end iterator when it has been advanced `n` times. `limited_end` returns an end iterator of the same type, so it compares equal *either* if the underlying iterators are equal, *or* if one of the iterators was created with `limited_end` and the other one has run `n` down to zero.

I don't have the code for this handy, but it's basically how you get `_n` equivalents of all the standard algorithms, not just `copy_n`. In this case, we want `transform_n`, but there isn't one.

An alternative to `transform` would be to use `copy_n` with a `boost::transform_iterator` wrapped around `m.rbegin()`. I won't do that here either, because I always have to check the docs to use `transform_iterator`.

Comment: Note that this fills the vector in reverse order. :)

Comment: @Xeo: it fills the vector in the same order as the questioner's code. Everyone else fills it in reverse order ;-) The difference is worth noting for future uses, but the questioner doesn't care about the order anyway.

Comment: Ha, you're right.. dammit. :) FWIW, instead of `transform_iterator`, just use the `transformed` adaptor from Boost.Range. Or, since it will boil down to the same thing, just `map_values` as in my answer. :)